# How to get the height of an Image in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, image, getimagesize

I have this code in **Silverlight**:

```
Image image = new Image();
BitmapImage bitmapImage= TheDatasourceManager.GetBitmapImage("blackPencil");
image.Source = bitmapImage;
image.Stretch = Stretch.None;
image.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
image.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
image.Margin = new Thickness(88, 88, 0, 0);
grid.Children.Add(image);
```

Now I want to find out the **height** of the image.

- in **WPF** I can get it with **image.Source.Height** but this is not available in Silverlight
- **bitmapImage.Height** doesn't exist either
- when I debug and examine the image object, I eventually get to **PixelHeight** which has an accurate height, but I can't seem to access it
- I find **image.ActualHeight** but it is 0.

**How can I get the height of the image?**

Answer (score 0):

I finally found it, it's just **bitmapImage.PixelHeight**. Since I'm not stretching it, seems to work fine.

Comment: Can you please help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22627245/change-the-orientation-based-on-image-width-and-height